# Replacement for Vern Buerg's list.com in 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, pipe, viewer

I would like to find a replacement for list.com, specifically the ability to accept piped input. For example:

```
p4 sync -n | list
```

which accepts the output of the perforce command and displays the results in the viewer/editor for manipulation or saving. I know that I would send the output to a file and then open the file in the viewer/editor but I use it for temporary results.

List.com doesn't work on 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: I am also looking for list.com for the windows command line. Requirements are very simple:
The same view that pops up when original list.com was run, with ability to graphically explore folders and press x to exit into the explored folder. By graphically I mean, it should act and look 1:1 like if you run list in dosbox, preferably supporting live-resizing of the window. To make it one would probably want to look at pdcurses win32a testcurs.c sample.

Comment: apparently it had the ability to expand folders.. in which case, this may be of interest winfile (as used in win 3.1)  but in Win7.. http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~davidsch/vistafm/

Comment: Look for zblist. I just got it. <http://www.bizer.com/zblist/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe someone is working on a replacment.  See http://mysite.verizon.net/yellowspoon

Comment: That site no longer exists and this is a good example of why it is recommended not to give link-only answers.

Comment: now it is at http://www.bizer.com/zblist/ you can download the beta and it works, boy what memories that brings up, if someone knows a link to the non-beta without startup message ...

Answer (score 2):

A good 32-bit Windows-based alternative to Vern Buerg's List is Charles Prineas' "V".  Find it at http://www.fileviewer.com.

Answer (score 1):

The [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) utility can display text read from standard input.  You can download 32-bit Windows binaries of the program, and Microsoft claims most programs designed for a computer running a 32-bit version of Windows will work on a computer running 64-bit versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate list.com file browsing and viewing features with **vifm** and **less**.
They are both freely available for windows.
After vifm installation just customize the "vi command" in the configuration file, and replace it with "less" (set vicmd = less \ -C)
You can also have a single pane display if you prefer so (with the "only" option).

Finally you can create a list.bat which calls vifm and changes the current directory on exit. This is the batch file content.

```
@echo off
for / f "delims =" %% i in ('vifm --choose-dir -% 1') do IF "%%i" NEQ "" (cd %%i)
```

More details in [list.com lives on my blog](https://giacomoblog.info/blog/236/2018/08/31/list-com-lives/)